# Copy & Paste hijacking in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, malware

I'm having a strange issue in Google Chrome. When I attempt to copy a URL from the location bar, pasting it into a new tab results in the output:

```
file://localhost/.apdisk
```

It doesn't happen in any other browsers or applications. I have tried:

1. Removing all extensions
2. Clearing browser data (all history, cookies, etc, since beginning of time)
3. Deleting and reinstalling Chrome

Nothing seems to work! I have tried Googling like mad, but can't find anybody else with this problem. Nervous that it's some kind of malware/hijacking.

Mac OS X: 10.9.5
Chrome: 44.0.2403.125

Comment: Try to install Chrome Canary and try it there

Comment: Good suggestion, but the problem persists in Canary. I'd also like a solution that solves the problem, since I'll still need to use standard Chrome for developing and testing.

Comment: I have to doubt its malware if it doesn't affect anything but chrome (there's no garuntee since .apdisk is a macosx file), honestly given the problem, it'd probably be better to see if you can submit a ticket to chrome devs instead of asking here only because it seems to be big thing for chrome... .not that i think they'll let you know

Comment: Thanks, @Daemedeor. I've had poor luck with getting responses to Chromium issues in the past. But giving it a shot: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516907

Comment: does issue pertain in other browsers as well?

Comment: Nope, only Chrome.

Comment: try updating chrome and let me know

Comment: I'm on the most recent version of Chrome (but this has been an ongoing issue). As I stated above, I've gone so far as to delete all browser history and do a complete reinstall of the browser. The issue persists.

Comment: Try running AdwareMedic it has updated signatures just to check if the browser is infected

Comment: I had adware issues in past with Chrome (windows) where i dug up and deleted an extension (and temp files about it), ran numerous tools and reinstalled and it kept appearing again. I 'think' i did a hard-reset (and offline install) of chrome in the end. I looked through my history but couldnt see exact page that helped me in the end, but this is re. reset: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en

Comment: I'm away from the machine that has this issue. @h0lyalg0rithm will try AdwareMedic and reward you the bounty, post-fact, if it helps.

Comment: Ditto @DanielBrose; although I did a complete reinstall I don't think I ever tried the hard reset. Will let you know if it works when I'm back at the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @h0lyalg0rithm ran [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware for Mac](http://www.adwaremedic.com/index.php) but it came up empty.

Comment: @Daniel Brose tried resetting Chrome; the issue persists.